# Owl Carousel not working as intended on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Right now, whenever I click on the right button, the slide does not change. The block quote does change though, but it overlaps on the current quote, and once this happens, the button no longer works.

Here are the files in my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require owl.carousel
//= require_tree .
```

Here are the files in my application.css:

```
*= require owl.carousel
*= require owl.theme
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

Here is the code in my html.erb:

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="testimonial-slider" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="testimonial">
                <div class="pic">
                    <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial-content">
                    <p class="description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur     adipisicing elit. A aliquam amet animi blanditiis consequatur debitis dicta distinctio, enim error eum iste libero modi nam natus perferendis possimus quasi sint sit tempora voluptatem. Est, exercitationem id ipsa ipsum laboriosam perferendis temporibus!
                    </p>
                    <h3 class="testimonial-title">Williamson
                        <small class="post">Web Developer</small>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="testimonial">
                <div class="pic">
                    <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial-content">
                    <p class="description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aliquam amet animi blanditiis consequatur debitis dicta distinctio, enim error eum iste libero modi nam natus perferendis possimus quasi sint sit tempora voluptatem. Est, exercitationem id ipsa ipsum laboriosam perferendis temporibus!
                    </p>
                    <h3 class="testimonial-title">kristiana
                        <small class="post">Web Designer</small>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in my css:

```
.testimonial {
    border-left: 3px solid #6ab33e;
    padding: 100px 0 100px 275px;
    position: relative;
}

    .testimonial:before,
    .testimonial:after {
        content: "";
        width: 320px;
        height: 55px;
        border-right: 3px solid #6ab33e;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }

    .testimonial:before {
        border-top: 3px solid #6ab33e;
        top: 0;
    }

    .testimonial:after {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #6ab33e;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .testimonial .pic {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }

        .testimonial .pic img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

    .testimonial .description {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #7a7e82;
        line-height: 27px;
        position: relative;
    }

        .testimonial .description:before {
            content: "\f10d";
            font-family: fontawesome;
            position: absolute;
            top: -70px;
            left: 0;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #7a7e82;
        }

    .testimonial .testimonial-title {
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: #22272c;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    .testimonial .post {
        display: block;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #6ab33e;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

.owl-theme .owl-controls {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

    .owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
        background: #6ab33e;
        border-radius: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }

.owl-prev:before,
.owl-next:before {
    content: "\f053";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #fff;
}

.owl-next:before {
    content: "\f054";
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .testimonial {
        padding: 80px 0 80px 265px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .testimonial {
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
    }

        .testimonial:before,
        .testimonial:after {
            border: none;
        }

        .testimonial .pic {
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .testimonial .description {
            margin-top: 15px;
        }

            .testimonial .description:before {
                content: "";
            }
}
```

And finally here is the code in my .js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    itemsDesktop:[1000,2],
    itemsDesktopSmall:[979,1],
    itemsTablet:[768,1],
    pagination:false,
    navigation:true,
    slideSpeed:1000,
    singleItem:true,
    transitionStyle:"goDown",
    navigationText:["",""],
    autoPlay:false
  });
});
```

Right now, the display is OK, but the button and transition is not working as intended.

Comment: What happens right now exactly? A little more explanation about the behavior it is currently presenting will help debug it.

Comment: Right now when you click the button to move through the scroller what happens?

Comment: I am trying to achieve this: jqueryrain.com/tutorial/testimonial/demo41, but right now, whenever I click on the right button, the slide does not change. The block quote does change though, but it overlaps on the current quote, and once this happens, the button no longer works.